# dynamic range in slice or array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, slice

I have python script that generates IP Subnet info from netaddr.

```
from netaddr import *
ipnetwork = raw_input("Enter IP address: ")
ip = IPNetwork(ipnetwork)
print "Network ID:", ip.network
print "Network Broadcast:", ip.broadcast
print "Subnet Mask:", ip.netmask
print "Prefix Length:", ip.prefixlen
print "Wildcard Mask:", ip.hostmask
print "Network Size:", ip.size

print "Host range is:", ip[1], "-", ip[-2]
for ip in IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts():
    print '%s' % ip
```

This works. Where I am having trouble is that I would like to "reserve" the first and last three addresses. Here's an example of my current output:

```
Enter IP address: 192.168.100.17/28
Network ID: 192.168.100.16
Network Broadcast: 192.168.100.31
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
Prefix Length: 28
Wildcard Mask: 0.0.0.15
Network Size: 16
Host range is: 192.168.100.17 - 192.168.100.30
192.168.100.17
192.168.100.18
192.168.100.19
192.168.100.20
192.168.100.21
192.168.100.22
192.168.100.23
192.168.100.24
192.168.100.25
192.168.100.26
192.168.100.27
192.168.100.28
192.168.100.29
192.168.100.30
```

What I would like to have as a result is

```
192.168.100.17 Reserved
192.168.100.18 Reserved
192.168.100.19 Reserved
192.168.100.20
192.168.100.21
192.168.100.22
192.168.100.23
192.168.100.24
192.168.100.25
192.168.100.26
192.168.100.27
192.168.100.28 SW2-VLAN 100
192.168.100.29 SW1-VLAN 100
192.168.100.30 HSRP VLAN 100
```

I thought slicing would work and it does, until I choose a different subnet length. I can't find out how to dynamically slice address four (the first non-reserved) to the last address minus three. I have not been able to find any solution (slice, array, index) where it would be dynamic depending on the subnet size minus the first and last three addresses. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by the question. If you're looking to manage the `IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts()` you'll probably want to just, for the sake of simplicity, list comprehend them.

```
def handle(i, data):
    # Each ip, or 'data', can be returned as a
    # new value to fill that list or we could return
    # The objects themselves.
    if i < 3:
        return str(data) + " Reverse"
    elif i > (total - 3):
        return str(data)
    else:
        return str(data) + " SW1-VLAN 100"

ips_to_manage = [handle(i, addr) for i, addr in \
                 enumerate(IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts())]
for ip in ips_to_manage:
    print '%s' % ip
```

You'll have to find out total yourself. `len(IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts())` shoud do the trick.
This way, you can simply handle them as you please.

This is just printing them however, if you want to do something else, as in return the objects themselves, you're more then welcome to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code but I get syntax error at elif, looks like that is not supported in a comprehend list. Is there another way to take the iteration and put it in a string/array/dict?

Comment: Well the elif should be just fine in this example. I'm assuming you replaced the `# ...` on each of the lines with code to actually handle the data? What's the syntax error you're getting?